# Show posts from last 7 days with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display posts from a Custom Post Type which have been published over the past 7 days. I will then have a button which says **Next 7 days** which a user can click and it will obviously show the next 7 days.

The code below seems to do the trick. The one thing I'm stuck on is the pagination, how will it work displaying the next 7 days? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'properties',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',

    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '1 week ago'
          )
      )
  ); ?>

  <?php $propertyInspection = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
  <?php if ( $propertyInspection->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $propertyInspection->have_posts() ) : $propertyInspection->the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_field('property-address'); ?>
    <?php the_field('property-suburb'); ?>

   <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

create another $args array with current date (or date with next 7 days) on button click(submit) and fetch next 7 days posts same as this.
then merge both resulting objects (also sun their post count)